# dotnet core 3.1 webapis on a Mac with a self-signed certificate errors

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, ssl-certificate

I want to develop dotnet core 3.1 webapis on a Mac with a self-signed certificate and not the dev-certs generated one as I need an additional SAN (10.0.2.2) for Android development in the cert. I would prefer the keychain but am fine with a pfx file but I can't get either of them working.

I have been able to create the certificate and import it into the keychain:

```
openssl req -config https.config -new -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -extfile https.config -extensions v3_req -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out https.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out https.pfx -inkey key.pem -in https.crt -password pass:Password1
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain https.crt
```

Here is the configuration in my appsettings.Development.json based on the directions to ***Replace the default certificate*** in the [Endpoint configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration) section of [Kestrel web server implementation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration):

```
"Certificates": {
  "Default": {
            "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
            "StoreName": "My",
            "Subject": "CN=localhost",
            "AllowInvalid": true 
  }
}
```

I get this error:

'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'The requested certificate CN=localhost could not be found in CurrentUser/My with AllowInvalid setting: True.'

toggling AllowInvalid did not help either.

I saw an example of somebody who got the keychain working in [.NET Core Kestrel with SSL](http://www.philipermish.com/blog/how-to-use-ssl-with-dotnet-core-and-kestrel/) with dotnet 2.0

I have also tried to get it working with a pfx file:

```
"Certificates": {
  "Default": {
    "Path": "https.pfx",
    "Password": "Password1"
  }
}
```

and that has gotten me to this error, which is an improvement over where I was a few hours ago:

An unhandled exception of type 'Interop.AppleCrypto.AppleCommonCryptoCryptographicException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'MAC verification failed during PKCS12 import (wrong password?)'

Has anybody had success in getting this to work on a Mac, either using the keychain or file approach with a custom self-signed certificate?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @BenjaminSalerno, no. I am able to get it working on an android emulator with a .pfx/password combination but that didn't help for an iOS simulator. I have tried a number of times over the years and am determined to fight through it and solve it this time.